# How to make a bootstrap input field "transparent"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the border from a bootstrap input `form-control`. 
After setting `border-color:white` i'm getting this

[image]

How can i lose this top border ? 
I thought it might be a shadow property but ... nothing.

This is the markup

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control transparent-input" type='text' name='name' placeholder="Field title..."  required>
</div>
```

bootstrap v3.1.1

**EDIT :**

None of the solution below is working. 
see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2998/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set background color using `rgba()` also add `border:none;` to remove the border

```
<style>
    input.transparent-input{
       background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
       border:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

The last value `0` will make the background transparent

or simply set background color as `transparent`.

```
<style>
    input.transparent-input{
       background-color:transparent !important;
       border:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

add `!important` to override the existing style

Comment: Thanks for the response  - please take a look at the fiddle in the edit.

Comment: add `box-shadow:none !important;`

Answer (score 2):

with bootstrap class you can make it transparent ...just apply this class to your code .*`bg-transparent`*

Answer (score 1):

```
.transparent-input { background: tranparent; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the background-color.

```
.transparent-input {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   border:none;
}
```

You can change the background color to (0,0,0) and its opacity to '0'.
Also `use border:none`. And try using `!important` to override the existing style if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting box shadow to none. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp